# Updating existing list with new data with constant time?

Tags: arrays, performance, typescript

So the problem is O(1) or Constant Time, I need to compare an array of class T that will get updated with some other data set at a later time. The items length in this example are small, but imagine a much larger data set of say a 2000 and you get the problem. Using Typescript how do I update an existing list with a new list in the most time efficient way possible???

```js
let movies: Array<Movie> = getMovies();
let updatedMovies: Array<Movie> = getUpdatedMovies();

// Delete ones that no longer exist within the new data set
let remainingMovies: Array<Movie> = movies.filter((value) => {
    return updatedMovies.some((value2) => {return value2.identifier == value.identifier});
});

// Update existing items or push a new one (ES6 Only)
updatedMovies.forEach(updatedMovie => {
    let item = remainingMovies.find(value => { return value.identifier == updatedMovie.identifier});
    if (item) {
        item = updatedMovie;
    }
    else {
        remainingMovies.push(updatedMovie);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `item = updatedMovie` supposed to be a no-op?  Because it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're only going to get O(1) time if you can simply replace the old array with the new array.

```
let easiestRemainingMovies: Array<Movie> = updatedMovies; // replace, O(1)
```

You can't do better than O(n) if you need to do something for each element in the array.  Your existing code looks like O(n<sup>2</sup>) since it does nested iterations.  You can get O(n) or close to it if you convert from an array to a hash map (e.g., plain JS object or `Map`) keyed by a unique identifier.  For example:

```
// put movies into hash, O(n)
const moviesHash: { [k: string]: Movie | undefined } = {};
movies.forEach(movie => moviesHash[movie.identifier] = movie) 

// process updatedMovies using map, O(n)
let betterRemainingMovies: Movie[] = updatedMovies.map(updatedMovie => {
  let item = moviesHash[updatedMovie.identifier]; // O(1) lookup
  if (item) {
    // update existing item somehow here
    return item;
  } else {
    return updatedMovie;
  }
});
```

Be warned that "most efficient way possible" is a difficult goal to achieve or even measure.  Different JavaScript engines behave in different ways.  Just using array methods like `map()`, `filter()`, `forEach()`, could potentially be slower than a plain old `for` loop... or maybe not, if your JS engine can optimize away the callback functions.  Usually the real issue isn't "most efficient way possible" but "efficient enough for my real-world scenario in the environments I need".

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for updating n items is **at least** O(n). In your implementation it is about O(n * m + k * m), where the letters are the length of the 3 movie arrays. To reduce that closer to O(n), you can create a lookup object for near constant lookup. For example (not tested):

```js
let movies: Array<Movie> = getMovies(), updatedMovies: Array<Movie> = getUpdatedMovies();

let updatedMoviesLookup = updatedMovies.reduce((obj, val) => (obj[val.identifier] = val, obj), {});

let remainingMovies: Array<Movie> = movies.filter(val => val.identifier in updatedMoviesLookup);
```